# SQL join a table that has an array field with the primary key of another table

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have table called Patients which has a field called related_forms_ids that has an array of forms ids and makes a reference to the form id on the forms table

```
[
 'formId1',
 'formId2',
 'formId3'
]
```

and I have the forms table that has these fields

```
{
 formId,
 formName
}
```

I need to join the patients table with the forms table using the related_forms_ids and the formName fields so I get the form name for the patients forms. How can I do it?
I'm trying to query using Google BigQuery

Comment: I know you probably can't control this, but it's poor schema design. It's pretty NEVER a good idea to put array data in a column, and you're about to find out one reason why.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. As @JoelCoehoorn says, this is really bad design but to get round it you’ll probably need a flatten function to get patient records with one form each and then join this to your forms table

Comment: This explains how to flatten (unnest) the array which will give you a structure you can use: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this

```
 SELECT P.*, F.Name
 FROM (SELECT *, UNNEST(related_forms_ids) AS related_form_id
       FROM Patient
 ) AS P
 LEFT JOIN Forms F ON P.related_form_id = F.id
```

This will give you all the forms in multiple rows